# Is there a way to erase all duplicates in a file and count how many duplicates there are while keeping original order of file

Tags: linux, shell, text, command-line, archlinux

I have a file like this

```
2/2
2/2
2/2
3/3
1/1
1/1
2/2
1/1
3/3
```

etc..

I want to delete all duplicates of the individual numbers and count how many there are of each number but keep their original order like this

```
4 2/2
2 3/3
3 1/1
```

I tried

```
sort myfile.txt | uniq -c
```

but this returns an output like this and doesnt keep it in order of the first instance in the file

```
2 3/3
4 2/2
3 1/1
```

I also tried just uniq -c on its own but that doesn't take out all of the duplicates. I running Arch Linux on the most recent kernel so I need the commands to work for that.

Sorry this was so confusing but any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
awk '
  # This first line simply ensures that `order` is an array
  BEGIN {delete order[0]}
  ! ($1 in seen) {order[length(order)+1] = $1}
  {seen[$1]++} 
  END {for (i in order) print seen[order[i]], order[i]}
' data.txt
```

In this script, we maintain two associate arrays ("dictionaries" or "hashes" in other languages):

- `order` records the order in which we encounter new values, and
- `seen` records how many times we have seen a particular value

After processing the data, we iterate through `order` to get the values in the order in which they appeared, and we look up their count in the `seen` array.

Given your sample input, this produces:

```
4 2/2
2 3/3
3 1/1
```

Comment: An alternate implementation: `!seen[$1]++ {order[n++] = $1}` then in the END block `for (i=0; i<n; i++) ...` -- looping with `for (i in a)` does not guarantee the order of the indices, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne 'push @order, $_ if !$seen{$_}++; END { print "$seen{$_} $_" for @order; }' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

Array `@order` keeps the input lines in the order of the input, first occurrence of each line only (thanks to `if !$seen{$_}++` condition). Hash `%seen` has unique input lines as keys, and the number of occurrences as values.

The `END { ... }` block prints the contents of the hash `%seen` in the order seen in the input (thanks to `@order`).

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)